# SXA Search Boosting Throws Error

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search

I have configured the search scope for `SXA (Sitecore 9.3)` and it works as expected. However, when I try to add boost configuration to the search scope it throws the below error.

> Invalid Method Call Argument Type: Field - FieldNode - Field: _name - System.String. Only constant arguments are supported.

It happens with any field added in the boost configuration. 
[image]

The search query works again if I remove all the rules. The error in the log file is below:

```
26380 20:12:20 WARN  Results endpoint exception
Exception: System.NotSupportedException
Message: Invalid Method Call Argument Type: Field - FieldNode - Field: _name - System.String. Only constant arguments is supported.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.ValidateMethodCallArguments(IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.EvaluateMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCall)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.VisitWhereMethod(MethodCallExpression methodCall)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.VisitCountMethod(MethodCallExpression methodCall)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionParser.Parse(Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.GenericQueryable`2.GetQuery(Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.GenericQueryable`2.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetResults(QueryModel model)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please check your Search logs, and post the query which is been logged while calling this?

Comment: @Poola did you ever find a solution to this issue? Sitecore support patch?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening a support ticket with Sitecore and they identified this as a known bug.

The hotfix I received today is `SC Hotfix 418336-1 SXA 9.3.0.2589`.

Consider contacting them for the latest hotfix, as it may include other fixes to SXA.

Comment: By any chance do you have a link to this Hotfix? Thank you